# How to debug neovim lsp custom command

Tags: vue.js, lua, neovim, language-server-protocol

I am attempting to get the [volar vue language server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-vue-languageservice) to work in place of vetur for neovim's native lsp.

Using both [lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) and [lspinstall](https://github.com/kabouzeid/nvim-lspinstall) I was able to create a working custom install for `sumneko_lua` (unrelated but had to manually build due to some issues with the built-in `:LspInstall lua`). Below is that code duplicated and modified for an attempt at using this new vue server:

```
local vue_config = require'lspinstall/util'.extract_config('vuels')
vue_config.default_config.cmd = {'node', './node_modules/vscode-vue-languageservice/out/index.js', '--stdio'}

require'lspinstall/servers'.newvue = vim.tbl_extend('error', vue_config, {
    install_script = [[
      ! test -f package.json && npm init -y --scope=lspinstall || true
        npm install vscode-vue-languageservice@latest
    ]],
    uninstall_script = nil
})
```

Running `:LspInstall newvue` installs properly, however `:LspInfo` shows this language server is attached to the buffer (of a .vue file) but not active. I believe the issue is with this path: `./node_modules/vscode-vue-languageservice/out/index.js`. It exists, but may not be the correct entry point? The default vue ls simply has `vls` as the command because it provides a binary. Am I missing something in this package? I have yet to come across another language server without a single binary to pick out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try an absolute path to the out.js file? In my pretty elaborate config for a custom Volar install I'm using something just `/home/myuser/dev/volar/packages/server/out/index.js` (where the `volar` folder is just the whole volar cloned github repo). My full config is [here](https://github.com/sethidden/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/nvim/lua/sh_volar.lua#L130)

I don't think you can use relative paths like you did. I know you're assuming that the "./node_modules" means "workspace directory" but it's hard to tell in which directory nvim-lspconfig opens up those executables.

> I have yet to come across another language server without a single binary to pick out.

Volar also provides a binary, it's `volar-server` (after running `npm i -g @volar/server`), it's just with a custom install (ie. alongside the real volar) you can't use it, because I assume you want to use your local install with custom code.

---

As for more indepth debugging/logging, you can check `~/.cache/nvim/lsp.log` to see why the language server dies in detail.